# Rx: How to get the last element even if onError was called?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

I'm using RxJava, and I need to do 2 things:

- Get the last element emitted from the `Observable`
- Determine if `onError` was called, vs. `onCompleted`

I've looked at using `last` and `lastOrDefault` (which is actually the behavior I need), but I've not been able to work around `onError` hiding the last element. I would be OK with the Observable being used twice, once to get the `last` value and once to get the completion status, but so far I've only been able to accomplish this by creating my own `Observer`:

```
public class CacheLastObserver<T> implements Observer<T> {

    private final AtomicReference<T> lastMessageReceived = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<Throwable> error = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        error.set(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T message) {
        lastMessageReceived.set(message);
    }

    public Optional<T> getLastMessageReceived() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(lastMessageReceived.get());
    }

    public Optional<Throwable> getError() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(error.get());
    }
}
```

I've no problem with making my own `Observer`, but it feels like Rx should be better able to meet this use-case of "get the last element emitted before completion`". Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
source.materialize().buffer(2).last()
```

In the error case the last emission will be a list of two items being the last value emitted wrapped as a `Notification` and the error notification. Without the error the second item will be the completion notification.

Note also that if no value is emitted then the result will be a list of one item being the terminal notification.

Comment: Is there a way to get the last emitted item, not the last received one, this is a nice approach although for getting the last item on the onNext call, but not from the emission of the initial Observable. (ie. emitting, 1,2,3, crash before the 4, then I should have a crash and item 4, currently you will get 3 with this method).

Comment: for a source to emit 1,2,3, error, 4 is against the Observable contract and thus not supported by RxJava. You would have to suppress throwing of  the error and emit it as onNext emission to make that happen.

Comment: This doesn't work on observables with an odd number of items (the complete/error notification is in a singleton list). Even `source.materialize().buffer(2, 1).last()` doesn't solve because the last buffer will have lenght=1.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with:

```
source.materialize().withPrevious().last()
```

where `withPrevious` is (Kotlin):

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.withPrevious(): Observable<Pair<T?, T>> =
    this.scan(Pair<T?, T?>(null, null)) { previous, current -> Pair(previous.second, current) }
        .skip(1)
        .map { it as Pair<T?, T> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try onErrorResumeNext here you can see the rest or error handling operators https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach to solve your problem.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .map(number -> {
                    if (number == 4)
                        throw new NullPointerException();
                    else
                        return number;
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(t -> Observable.empty())
                .lastOrDefault(15)
                .subscribe(lastEmittedNumber -> System.out.println("onNext: " + lastEmittedNumber));
    }
}
```

It will emit `onNext: 3`

Hope that it helps.